# C++ STM32 user defined class constructor problems

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb, stm32

I'm having a problem with self made classes. I have a class where i can input a data structure. If i call the function from "old main.cpp", it fills a pre-existing structure and initializes hardware upon this info.

```
main.cpp (old way of handling, witch works):
UART UARTObj;
IO_t UART1_RX;
IO_t UART1_TX;
...
IOObj.begin(&UART1_RX, GPIOA, 3, GPIO_Mode_AF, GPIO_OType_PP, GPIO_PuPd_UP, GPIO_Speed_Level_3, GPIO_AF_1);
UARTObj.begin(USART2, 230400, &UART1_RX, &UART1_TX);
```

Because i want to keep my pin assignments to one place, i created a class called IOPin.

```
IOPin.h :
typedef struct IO_t{
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIOInfo;
GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx;
uint8_t GPIO_AF;
bool init;
}IO_t;

class IOPin
{
public:
IOPin(GPIO_TypeDef*, uint16_t, GPIOMode_TypeDef, GPIOOType_TypeDef, GPIOPuPd_TypeDef, GPIOSpeed_TypeDef);
IOPin(GPIO_TypeDef*, uint16_t, GPIOMode_TypeDef, GPIOOType_TypeDef, GPIOPuPd_TypeDef, GPIOSpeed_TypeDef, uint8_t GPIO_AF);
IO_t *PIN = new IO_t;
virtual
~IOPin ();
};
```

The theory is that i call the constructor with the info that is required for each object.
Later on, i call a function with this class attached. I take the struct from this class and put it through the same function like the old way.

```
main.cpp (new way of handling, witch gives problems) :
IOPin UART_RX(GPIOA, 3, GPIO_Mode_AF, GPIO_OType_PP, GPIO_PuPd_UP, GPIO_Speed_Level_3, GPIO_AF_1);
IOPin UART_TX(GPIOA, 2, GPIO_Mode_AF, GPIO_OType_PP, GPIO_PuPd_UP, GPIO_Speed_Level_3, GPIO_AF_1);
....
IOObj.begin(&UART_RX);
IOObj.begin(&UART_TX);
UARTObj.begin(USART2, 230400, &UART_RX, &UART_TX);
```

I'm using GDB as debugger, and cannot see anything that is wrong.

Problems:
If i rebuild the project, it works once.
Resetting the platform does not help.
Anyone an idea why this approach with the class does not work?
I've tried making this a pointer, putting it into the header file, etc..

Comment: Are you talking about full reset (program re-loaded to ram from some read-only memory, etc.)?

Comment: This particular piece of code is to initialize the pins. More specifically the pins of the UART. I'm getting no hardware faults, and the loop in my main function is reached. I'm not getting a good initialization of the pins though. If i change the setup to the old way, everything works. I thought it was a design error, but i am not sure..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK here's some tips that may eventually pan out to a full answer because it's hard to see exactly what's going on from the incomplete fragments posted in the question and this is going to be too long for a comment:

Don't use the heap when the stack will do. The C++11 declaration `IO_t *PIN = new IO_t` appears to be trivially replaceable with `IO_t PIN`. Where is `PIN` initialised with valid content? You don't show this, nor does `PIN` ever seem to be deleted.

Don't declare members `virtual` unless there's a very good reason for it. A `virtual` member instantly introduces a virtual function table, which is implemented in SRAM, which is your scarcest resource. Best practices that you were taught for PC programming don't apply here.

Comment: Yes, this most likely seems a heap problem. when allocating 1400 bytes in heap, i get lots of problems that malloc exits the application. Will investigate further! Thanks Andy

Answer (score 0):

Well first, i would defently not use dynamic allocations that come with toolchain. But better i wouldnt use dynamic allocation at all. it is a microcontroller, you run privileged mode and have access to all of the memory available on board.

Second, check your linker script if and initialization part. make sure it is properly set up. Especially your vtable